# how to combine two arrays with the same length into a two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
include 'core/init.php'; 
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

$check_like = mysql_query("SELECT liker, liker_username FROM `likes` WHERE `post_id`='$post_id' ");
                while($run_check_like = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_like)) {

                $post_liker[] = $run_check_like['liker'];

                $post_liker_profile[] = $run_check_like['liker_username'];           
        }   

include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
```

array one is $post_liker;
array two is $post_liker_profile;

i want to echo out sth. as $post[$post_liker][$post_liker_profile];

Comment: Note that there's an SQL injection exploit in the `post_id` field. Sanitize it with something like `intval()` or `addslashes()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using something like: [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)?

```
$post = array_combine($post_liker, $post_liker_profile);
```

Comment: yes it works but how can I echo out separate values of this array ? for exaple post[][]; using a foreach loop?

Comment: @RexhinHoxha Is [print_r](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) what you're looking for?

Comment: @RexhinHoxha `$post['liker-name']` returns the value, so I guess a for loop or however you want to traverse the array

Comment: for example $post[array_one_first_value][array_two_first_value];

Comment: @RexhinHoxha no, what combine does is `$post[array_one_first_value]` returns `array_two_first_value`.

Comment: but how can i echo out both informations liker name and liker username?

Comment: i want only values not the whole array

Answer (score 0):

$i=0;

$array[$i][$i]=$array_one[$i]."*".$array_two[$i];

try to use like this while storing and you can use split using * again if you need the values back.

if your array values contain * use some thing other that is not present.